# Cant seem to figure out sorting an array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compare

this is the class for the objects that fill my array

```
class InventoryItem implements Comparable<InventoryItem>{
String name;
double price = 0.0;
int quantity = 0;
int itemCount = 0;
public InventoryItem(String newName, double newPrice, int newQuantity){
    name = newName;
    price = newPrice;
    quantity = newQuantity;
    itemCount++;
}

public String toString(){
    String output = name + ", at " + Program4.moneyString(price) + " each.";
    output += " We have " + getQuantity() + " of them.\n";
    return output;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public int compareTo(InventoryItem other){
    return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
}
}
```

and my call to sort the array

```
public static void sortByName(InventoryItem[] array){
    Arrays.sort(array);
}
```

this gives me the errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at CSC120Program4.Program4.sortByName(Program4.java:97)
at CSC120Program4.Program4.processUserChoice(Program4.java:121)
at CSC120Program4.Program4.main(Program4.java:134)
```

I'm not quite experienced enough to know how to fix this or really what I'm doing wrong.

edit: array being built:

```
static InventoryItem[] inventoryItems = new InventoryItem[100];
public static void readAndStoreInventory(InventoryItem[] items, Scanner input){

    String[] params = new String[3];
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        String name = "";
        double value = 0.0;
        int quantity = 0;
        params = (input.nextLine().split("#"));
        name = params[0];
        value = Double.parseDouble(params[1]);
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(params[2]);
        items[lastInUse + 1] = new InventoryItem(name, value, quantity);
        lastInUse++;
    }
    input.close();
```

the file being read is as follows:

```
wooden baseball bat#3.67#10
rubber mallet#5.50#20
duffel bag#10.20#11
gold bar#9999.99#1
hitman rental#20000.00#99
minivan#15000.21#3
half full cup#2.00#10
half empty cup#10.00#10
lawn chair#12.34#100
used golf ball#0.99#2
cosby sweater#250.00#1
CSC120 cheatsheet#0.01#1
```

Comment: Where is your array in the code? I don't see any arrays initialized in your code..

Comment: updated with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays.sort(Object[])` expects that all elements in the array are `!= null` since it demands that

> all elements in the array must be *mutually* comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) ...

What you see is the result of `null.compareTo(something)`.

Your `InventoryItem[] array` has presumable 100 slots, but not all of them are filled.

To fix that, you could

- copy the non-null data into a correctly sized array
- sort just the filled subset via [`Arrays.sort(Object[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-int-int-) (with `0, lastIndexUsed` as params).
- Provide a `Comparator` that can handle `null`. With one the algorithm is no longer `null.compareTo(something)` but `comparator.compare(null, something)` which does not result in a NPE. See [How to sort an array of objects containing null elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556104/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-containing-null-elements)
- use a `List`

Comment: THANK YOUUUUU. We *have* to use arrays due to it being to my professors guidelines for the assignment so using a list wasnt an option unfortunately. its dumb i know. but using the index values made it work flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array with 100 elements but you only creating a few items.
So when you sort it, it will also sort these null objects. You should use a List for this purpose.

You could also try to add a null-ptr check:

```
public int compareTo(InventoryItem other){
if (other != null){
    return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
}
return 0
}
```

A dirty fix would be to get the size of the elements and sort only the added elements: (Better way would be to use a list from the start)

```
public static void sortByName(InventoryItem[] array){
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++)
            if (array[i] != null){
            counter ++;
            break;
        }
    Arrays.sort(array, 0, counter-1);
}
```

Comment: @JoshPeel, this is not supposed to fix the underlying issue. This is simply checking if the values within the array are not null..

Comment: @ryekayo actually it should fix the issue...the `null` elements should be at the end of the `array` when done.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Probably means a `null` is having properties accessed on it. Probably in here:

```
public int compareTo(InventoryItem other){
  return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
}
```

So one of the `name` is null. So probably here:

```
params = (input.nextLine().split("#"));
name = params[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The InventoryItem array is initialized as 100, and if you don't read in 100 rows, then you'll have null pointers for the non-existent indexes.  You'll need to use a List, rather than a java array.

```
List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = new List<InventoryItem>();
```

then when you add them do something like this,

```
inventoryItems.add(new InventoryItem(name, value, quantity));
```

Comment: its initialized at -1